# Criteria behind which elements are inline vs block

Tags: html, css, block, inline

I once read that all elements that can have a width assigned are block elements. This seems to be true for a majority of all elements. But, there are also quite a couple for which this is incorrect (e.g. button, input, textarea etc. can all have a width assigned to it but they are inline elements).

Which criteria did W3C use when deciding on which elements become inline vs which become block?

Comment: `span` is inline, `<span style="display:block">` is block now....i don't see w3c criterion's affecting my code as they gave workarounds for it too!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: That's because you're changing it with CSS. This question seems to be asking about the defaults for HTML elements.

Comment: @BoltClock : hey mate...i so wanted your response to get in touch...!! :) ....why i posted that comment is because, i don't really see a question because all *by-default properties* are changed some where or other using css, consider `html,body{margin:0;padding:0}` <= didn't we change the defaults here, why bother about other css then, as long as it doesn't violates the semantics completely????.... your thoughts..?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that are expected to appear within a paragraph of test are *phrasing* elements, and therefore rendered as *inline-level*. Other elements are *block-level*. Another way of saying the same thng is to say that elements which expect a new line before and after them are block-level, otherwise they are inline-level.

Which is only partially related to why width can be applied to them or not. What matters is whether or not they are rendered as a single rectangular box, or whether their contents can be broken across a line. If they can, then width is not applied, probably because it's quite hard to work out what a width setting really means when it starts and ends on different lines. Inline-level elements that cannot be broken across lines, i.e. elements that are `inline-block`, `inline-table` or replaced elements, can have width settings applied.